# How to change QLineEdit border color only

Tags: qt5

My goal is to change the border color of QLineEdit based on the value of a property "valid".

I have added this style:

QLineEdit[valid=false] {border: 1px solid red}

And when I set the property "valid" to false and do the unpolish(), polish() dance I see the red border.

But the border radius is changed as is the padding.

How do I only change the border color and leave the padding and border radius at the default value?

I have considered finding the values of the border radius and padding,
but did not find an API call that will return this information.

Comment: You cannot. The only way you can achieve is subclassing the QLineEdit.